# Understanding Perron's formula by calculation of residues

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, residue-calculus

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of Perron's formula, which assets that, for the Dirichlet series $\alpha(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n n^{-s}$ and the coefficient sum $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} a_n$ we have:

$A(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma _0+i \infty} \alpha(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds $

for $\sigma _0 >0$.

My text book (H. L. Montgomery and R. C. Vaughan. Multiplicative number theory. I. Classical theory, chapter 5.1 page 137) says that we should expect the above formula to be true, as we can calculate the integral using calculus of residues. It further says that:

$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma _0+i \infty} y^s \frac{1}{s} ds
= $ $\{ 1 \text{ if } y>1, \quad 0 \text{ if } 0<y<1,\quad \frac{1}{2} \text{ if } y=1 \} $

I have two problems with this:

1. When I learned about residues I learned that

$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma}f(z) dz = \sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Res}\left(f,a_j\right)$

only when $\gamma$ is a simple closed path in a simply connected domain. But the path from $\sigma_0-i\infty$ to $\sigma_0+i\infty$ is not simply connected?

2. If we say that the equation for the residue holds, we'll now need to calculate the residue. The pole, as far as I can see, is simple so we need to find the limit:

$\lim _{s \longrightarrow 0} \frac{y^s}{s}(s-0)=\lim _{s \longrightarrow 0} y^s $

But I can't see how the limit of $y^s$ can be anything but $1$. How does this work out?

Comment: Essentially, you have to consider $\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{y^{s}}{s}ds$ as a part of a closed path and then you have to choose a suitable path for different choices of $y$. After that, consider the limit as $T\rightarrow+\infty$. Take a look, for a proof, at this classical book, page 105 : https://books.google.it/books?id=SFztBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=davenport+multiplicative+number+theory&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjojKvA6qXuAhUEwKQKHRJ7AhwQuwUwAXoECAQQCQ#v=onepage&q=davenport%20multiplicative%20number%20theory&f=false

Comment: Intuitively  you need to make the integral small in absolute value, so for $y>1$ you need to move to the left so real part of $s$ negative as that controls the modulus, going through singularity at zero and get residue,  but for $0<y<1$ you move to the right to get a zero limit as real part of $s$ goes to infinity and no singularity so result zero  by cauchy; for $y=1$ integral oscillates so cannot use residues but you compute directly and the result comes from the imaginary part which  has an even arctan like primitive, while the real part has odd primitive so evaluates to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is a possible method for us to derive Perron's formula from scratch. If $\alpha(s)$ converges at $\Re s=\sigma_0$, then using OP's notation, we can obtain the following relation if we consider Stieltjes integration for $\Re s\ge\sigma_0$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha(s)
&=\int_{1^-}^\infty{\mathrm dA(x)\over x^s} \\
&=\left.{A(x)\over x^s}\right|_{1^-}^\infty+s\int_1^\infty A(x)x^{-s-1}\mathrm dx \\
&=s\int_0^\infty A(e^t)e^{-st}\mathrm dt
\end{aligned}
$$

This indicates that a Laplace transform relationship exists between the summatory function and the Dirichlet series:

$$
{\alpha(s)\over s}=\mathcal L\{A(e^t)\}(s)
$$

Consequently, by applying Mellin's inversion formula, we obtain

$$
A(e^t)={1\over2\pi i}\int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty}\alpha(s){e^{st}\over s}\mathrm ds
$$

Now, plugging in $x=e^t$ gives the Perron's formula

$$
A(x)={1\over2\pi i}\int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty}\alpha(s){x^s\over s}\mathrm ds
$$

In particular, if $x$ is an integer then the integral is interpreted as the Cauchy principal value:

$$
{A(x-0)+A(x+0)\over2}
$$